# How to get the last strtok?

Tags: c++, string, split, strtok

I want to split a "string" (delimiter `\`) to get the last occurrence. [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/849854192b6a8149) is the code I wrote:

```
char str[] ="D:\\Google Drive\\My Files\\Test.zip";
char * buffer = str;

sprintf(buffer, "%s", strtok(str,"\\"));
cout << buffer;
```

but it returns `D:` instead of `Test.zip` (the first occurrence, not the last). How would you do this task?

I need to use/keep sprintf (i.e. format string approch).

Comment: Why are you even using C strings and C APIs in what is supposedly a C++ program ? Why not write proper C++ code using e.g. `std::string` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [strrchr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) instead - it's more appropriate in this context, and both non-destructive and reentrant too:

```
char str[] ="D:\\Google Drive\\My Files\\Test.zip";
char * buffer = strrchr(str, '\\');
cout << buffer + 1;
```

If you really do have to keep the redundant and inefficient use of `sprintf` as per your question then you can of course do this:

```
char str[] ="D:\\Google Drive\\My Files\\Test.zip";
char buffer[256];
sprintf(buffer, "%s", strrchr(str, '\\') + 1);
cout << buffer;
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/9TTD7S)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry. But I need to use/keep sprintf (i.e. format string approch).

Comment: Well that seems silly - but I'll make it less efficient for you if that's what you need.

Comment: That's because I am in fact using WDL_string container https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/blob/master/WDL/wdlstring.h . And I can set/append string using "format string". There isn't .Split function for that container.

Comment: Don't forget to test for `buffer != NULL`, *especially* if the string to search is a user input.

Comment: Uhm, I guess so that's not the best approch for doing this using WDL_String. What do you suggest?

Comment: Also try using `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`